# why using gif.save command will terminate the graphical user interface in python?

Tags: python, gif

I made a GUI using Tkinter. I have a button with a function defined beneath it. Users can click the button and upload a .csv file, which is used to plot a figure and is saved into a frames list. I run the program in jupyter notebook and I upload a .csv file which generates a .gif file. The program asks me for a path-location to save the generated gif file. here are the codes.

```py
path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialfile = "Pre_Planed_Optimization_GIF", 
                                        title='Save it as "GIF_opt"',
                                        defaultextension='.gif')

gif.save(frames, path, duration=10)
```

The above procedure works fine on jupyter notebook. I used pyinstaller to make an exe file from the whole software. Here is the problem.
The software is functional for all other functions except for the gif part. It generates the gif file as I expected, however, once the gif is generated, the software is terminated!

My whole GUI is closed after generating gif file. Could anyone help me with a solution? I think something is not correct with `gif.save(frames, path, duration=10)` part. Once the gif library saves the gif file, it terminates the whole program. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an error message when the exe crashes? If not, I would suggest to call the exe from the command line window. Then you might be able to find out more about the reason why it crashes, because it usually prints the error messages there and you can still read it after the GUI crashed. Might be due to some hidden imports by the way.

Comment: Thanks. The exe file itself opens the CMD window too. I called the pyinstaller on the main file in a way to have a terminal/CMD prompt behind the main GUI so the user can see the errors even when uses the GUI directly. In another word, when the user opens the GUI, two windows will show up. the main GUI and the cmd prompt window. The error mentioned here, unfortunately, closes both windows at the same time.